# Understanding legacy pascal

Tags: scala, pascal, freepascal, legacy-code

So I need to understand what this code is doing. I don't know pascal or cryptography, and am struggling to understand what is going on in here. I need to reverse engineer `SHA1DigestToHex` into scala and am totally lost beyond learning pascal. Can you tell me what this function is doing? Or how I can go about figuring it out?

```
Function SHA1DigestToHex (const Digest : T160BitDigest) : String;
  Begin
    Result := DigestToHex (Digest, Sizeof (Digest));
  End;

Function DigestToHex (const Digest; const Size : Integer) : String;
  Begin
    SetLength (Result, Size * 2);
    DigestToHexBuf (Digest, Size, Pointer (Result)^);
  End;

Procedure DigestToHexBuf (const Digest; const Size : Integer; const Buf);
const s_HexDigitsLower : String [16] = '0123456789abcdef';
var I : Integer;
    P : PChar;
    Q : PByte;
  Begin
    P := @Buf;;
    Assert (Assigned (P), 'Assigned (Buf)');
    Q := @Digest;
    Assert (Assigned (Q), 'Assigned (Digest)');
    For I := 0 to Size - 1 do
      begin
        P^ := s_HexDigitsLower [Q^ shr 4 + 1];
        Inc (P);
        P^ := s_HexDigitsLower [Q^ and 15 + 1];
        Inc (P);
        Inc (Q);
      end;
  End;
```

---

### UPDATE

```
type
  PByte = ^Byte;
  PWord = ^Word;
  PLongWord = ^LongWord;
  T128BitDigest = record
    case integer of
      0 : (Int64s : Array [0..1] of Int64);
      1 : (Longs  : Array [0..3] of LongWord);
      2 : (Words  : Array [0..7] of Word);
      3 : (Bytes  : Array [0..15] of Byte);
    end;
  P128BitDigest = ^T128BitDigest;
  T160BitDigest = record
    case integer of
      0 : (Longs : Array [0..4] of LongWord);
      1 : (Words : Array [0..9] of Word);
      2 : (Bytes : Array [0..19] of Byte);
    end;
  P160BitDigest = ^T160BitDigest;

const
  MaxHashDigestSize = Sizeof (T160BitDigest);

Procedure DigestToHexBuf (const Digest; const Size : Integer; const Buf);
Function  DigestToHex (const Digest; const Size : Integer) : String;
Function  Digest128Equal (const Digest1, Digest2 : T128BitDigest) : Boolean;
Function  Digest160Equal (const Digest1, Digest2 : T160BitDigest) : Boolean;
```

Comment: Google "byte array to hex string" most likely solution [What is/are the Scala way(s) to implement this Java “byte to Hex” class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756166/what-is-are-the-scala-ways-to-implement-this-java-byte-to-hex-class)

Comment: This is not legacy Pascal, this perfectly current Pascal

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort its legacy from the perspective of our application.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: It may be legacy code for you, but it is not legacy Pascal. The title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It merely converts the bytes of the binary buffer passed in as `Buf` into a string of hexadecimal digits representing the same bytes in `Digest`.

So e.g. if Buf is the byte array (0x12, 0x34, 0x56), then afterwards Digest will be '123456'.

Here's a simpler Pascal (Delphi) version that does the same thing:

```
  function SHA1DigestToHex2(const Digest : T160BitDigest) : string;
  const s_HexDigitsLower : array[0..15] of char = '0123456789abcdef';
  var
    i, j: Integer;
  Begin
    SetLength(Result, sizeof(Digest) * 2);
    i := 1;
    j := 0;
    while j < sizeof(Digest) do begin
      Result[i] := s_HexDigitsLower[Digest.Bytes[j] shr 4];
      Result[i+1] := s_HexDigitsLower[Digest.Bytes[j] and $F];
      inc(i, 2);
      inc(j);
    end;
  End;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Its taking the binary buffer, and turning it into digest as a hexadecimal string?

Comment: Any idea how I would do that in scala? I don't understand how its doing that, or what a digest is.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Scala. Tag your question with `scala` also and someone with knowledge about that will probably see it.

Comment: Or maybe just explain more. Your first sentence looks like the function is `(Buf, Digest) -> String` but the example looks like `Bug -> String`. `SHA1DigestToHex` is `Digest -> Sting` though, so I'm still not sure what is going on. +1 for knowing pascal haha.

Comment: If you ask me, this code is awful - it was probably written by a C programmer :) If you can show how `T160BitDigest` is defined, I can quickly write a much cleaner Pascal version for you that does the same thing, and which will likely be a bit easier to port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110311/discussion-between-fresheyeball-and-500-internal-server-error).

Comment: Isn't it simply dcpcrypt?